# Eigen MatrixXd pointer passed as argument to a function causes segmentation faults

Tags: c++, pointers, eigen3

The [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) library has limitations with passing non-const Eigen variables as parameters to functions due so some issues with temporary object creation. However, they have provided several solutions and work arounds mentioned [here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicFunctionTakingEigenTypes.html) suggesting usage of the Ref templated class or passing const parameters and them casting away their constant-ness in the function.

However, they don't mention any limitations with passing Eigen matrices as pointers to functions.

```
void function(const int a, Eigen::MatrixXd* mat) {
   Eigen::MatrixXd temp_mat = Eigen::Matrix::Constant(2, 2, a);
   (*mat).topLeftCorner << temp_mat; 
}

Eigen::MatrixXd mat = Eigen::MatrixXd::Zero(5,5);
function(9, &mat);           // Seg Fault
```

I am not sure why do I get a segmentation fault in this code snippet.

Comment: Does 
  `Eigen::MatrixXd mat = Eigen::MatrixXd::Zero(5,5);
  Eigen::MatrixXd temp_mat = Eigen::Matrix::Constant(2, 2, a);
  mat.topLeftCorner << temp_mat;`
work?

Comment: Oh yes, it does.

Comment: I guess you forgot to write down the arguments of topLeftCorner. I guess that's where the error is. There are other mistakes, too. Please try to compile your code, before you post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void foo(const int a, Eigen::MatrixXd* mat)
{
    Eigen::MatrixXd temp_mat = Eigen::MatrixXd::Constant(2, 2, a);
    (*mat).topLeftCorner(2, 2) << temp_mat;
}


int main()
{
    Eigen::MatrixXd mat = Eigen::MatrixXd::Zero(5, 5);
    foo(9, &mat); 
    cout << mat;
}
```

works fine for me.

Comment: I tried to extract a very small snippet from my actual code and realized that it doesn't do justice to the question. Thanks for the help. Appreciate it.